# SQL / JPA "conditional" uniqueness a thing?

Tags: sql, jpa

I have a OneToMany Relation Ship in my entities. There is a entity article an a entity draft.
Every draft has a unique version in connected with an article.

```
aritcle_id | draft_id | version
-------------------------------
 1         | 1        | 1
 1         | 2        | 2
 1         | 3        | 3
 2         | 4        | 1
```

If I make the version 'unique' it is version-row-far unique is it possible to declare it article-row-far unique? So you can have duplicated versions but only if the version is attached to another article?

Comment: What is "version-row-far" and "article_row_far"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every draft has a unique version

You can implement this with a unique constraint.  I *think* it is:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_draft_version unique (draft_id, version);
```

If `draft_id` can be repeated on different articles, you can include all three columns:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_article_draft_version unique (article_id, draft_id, version);
```